# Batch file mangling a string with special chars and quotes inside a FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This code snippet below is stripped of all the extra junk, down to just the error-generating code,

> )"" was unexpected at this time.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
Set "regex="(Test_Health=(?!100))""
echo Regex is: %regex%

FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,5) DO (
Set "to_call=call crv.exe "%%I" %regex%"
echo About to call: !to_call!
)
```

Basically, in the real script, I'm trying to call a command-line tool that takes a complex string with potentially special chars in it, as well as a regex.

I figured out a workaround, which was to add a single caret (`^`) before `%%I`'s last quote:

```
Set "to_call=call crv.exe "%%I^" %regex%"
```

But that feels like a *dirty* hack. What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to get the desired behavior without a dirty hack?

Comment: I am not really understanding why you are setting a variable to a variable and then using that variable to execute a call to another command.  I think you are over complicating your code.

Comment: @Squashman Just the aftermath of shotgun debugging wonkiness. Trying to check variables before/after entering loops and delayed expansion as well as piping to files versus console. It's not trying to be efficient, just reproing the behavior. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your problem without a hack:

- Make sure that the `!` char. in your `regex` variable value is recognized as a *literal*:

  - `Set "regex=(Test_Health=(?^!100))"`
  - Due to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, *literal* `!` chars. inside `"..."` must be escaped as `^!`.
  - Note that the `<name>=<value>` token is double-quoted *as a whole*, to prevent additional interpretation of the value.
- Reference variable `regex` *delayed* inside the `for` loop body:

  - Use `!regex!` instead of `%regex%`.
  - To make the resulting command line more robust - even though it's not needed in this specific case - ensure that the value of `regex` is enclosed in double quotes (note that `%%I` - as a mere number - does *not* need quoting):
    `Set "to_call=call crv.exe %%I "!regex!""`

To put it all together:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

Set "regex=(Test_Health=(?^!100))"
echo Regex is: %regex%

FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,5) DO (
  Set "to_call=call crv.exe %%I "!regex!""
  echo About to call: !to_call!
)
```

yields:

```
Regex is: (Test_Health=(?100))
call crv.exe 1 "(Test_Health=(?!100))"
call crv.exe 2 "(Test_Health=(?!100))"
call crv.exe 3 "(Test_Health=(?!100))"
call crv.exe 4 "(Test_Health=(?!100))"
call crv.exe 5 "(Test_Health=(?!100))"
```

---

As for **what you did wrong**:

`%<name>%`-style variable references - except for the *loop* variable (`%%I` in this case) - are expanded inside the loop body (`(...)`) before the loop is even *parsed*, so the *values* of such variable references can *break* the loop.

Here's a **minimal example** that demonstrates the problem:

```
@echo off
Set "regex=))"

FOR %%I IN ("dummy") DO (
  rem !! breaks, because the up-front %regex% expansion causes a syntax error.
  echo %regex%
)
```

*Delaying* the expansion - by enclosing the variable name in `!...!`, assuming `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is in effect - bypasses this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "regex=))"

FOR %%I IN ("dummy") DO (
  rem OK - outputs "))"
  echo !regex!
)
```

Comment: Definitely the superior answer here. I'm so out of it that I forgot that I specifically asked for an answer that didn't seem like a dirty hack. I wouldn't call Magoo's answer a _dirty_ hack, but compared to this, yeah, definitely a solid diff and great breakdown. Unlike Magoo's answer, yours actually worked for more than ECHO too, meaning my command-line tool wasn't fussing at all over excess carets, and I was getting good results from my test strings and regexes ^_^

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
Set "regex="(Test_Health=(?^^^^!100^^)^^)""
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
echo Regex is: %regex%

FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,5) DO (
Set "to_call=call crv.exe "%%I" %regex%"
echo About to call: !to_call!
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Sort of depends on what your "desired behaviour" is. Unfortunately, you don't specify.

It's a matter of understanding how `cmd` works - by substitution, using escape characters and the sequence that this occurs.

The `echo` reporting the regex won't yield the correct result. Within the `for` however, each pair of carets is interpreted as a single caret, so the required escapes are as required for the expected output, presumably `call crv.exe "5" "(Test_Health=(?!100))"` and the like...

Comment: Yikes. Yeah, I tried a lot of different escape combinations, and re-orienting where the SETLOCALs were, but that kind of shotgun debugging leads to madness after a while... or Stack Overflow ... Or SS64! ^_^ Thanks, Magoo. Seeing as you only escaped the `!` and `)`s, it's safe to say I wouldn't have tried that _specific_ combination any time soon... phew! :D

Comment: Go figure... As soon as it echoes correctly, now the command-line tool is mad at excess `^`, hahaha! Can't wim 'um all...